# Google Script Only Working When Logged In

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Keeping in mind I am the most novice of programmers and figured most of this out from a tutorial...

I'm trying to setup a page to allow users (Gmail users or not) to upload files into my Google Drive account. People often need to give me files larger than what can be emailed. I want to be able to use my drive account similar to Dropbox. I've published it as a web app and the entire script works flawlessly from start to finish but only when I'm logged in to my own account in my browser. Your first thought is I need to allow access to "anyone, even anonymous" but I've already done that. The script also executes as "me". When not logged in the form shows up missing fields and produces a white screen without completing any kind of upload. Here is the incomplete form that shows up when I'm not logged in: [Incomplete Form - Not Logged In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiGcm.png)

And here is the code:

```
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

try {

var dropbox = "Public Upload";
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

var blob = form.myFile;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

return "<h1>Your File Has Been Uploaded Successfully!</h1><br>To upload additional files simply reload this page and complete the process again.<br><br>Once you have finished uploading all of your files please send me an email to confirm completion.";

} catch (error) {

return error.toString();
}

}
```

and form.html

```
<body style="background:navy; color:white;">
<form id="myForm">

<h1>You Are Uploading Files to Adam</h1>

<label>Name of Uploader (You)</label>
<input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Full Name">

<label>Brief Description of File</label>
<input type="text" name="fileName" placeholder="Session title, etc.">

<input type="file" name="myFile">

<input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
       onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">

<p style="color:yellow">Depending on the total size of your file uploading may take a few moments...</p>

</form>
</body>
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
}
</script>

<style>
input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

Again, novice programmer here, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is non-logged in user able to upload any file at all? If so is there any error message returned? I simply copy/pasted your script and executed and everything working fine for me. I am able to upload files with out logging in. I didn't made any changes at all to your code. Try creating a new script freshly and publish the script?

Comment: As @Srikanth said, what you should try is: in the script editor, do publish>deploy as web-app and then choose "new" in the project version. Copy the new web-app URL and test it to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code rings a bell. Is it from [labnol.org](http://labnol.org)?

I used it a couple of times to create a picture uploader with great success. You permissions seem to be set up fine; are you using Google for enterprise or is your standard mainstream Drive?

I now that in my company some APIs and some services can't be used in Google Apps Script; Drive is one of them (*admins don't allow scripts that use DriveApp*).

Comment: I honestly don't remember where exactly it came from. it's just a normal personal Drive account, no Google for enterprise